# How can I attempt to inhibit the hydrolysis/degeneration of aspartame?

Tags: hydrolysis

I've surfed the internet, looking for some possible inhibitors for the hydrolysis process of aspartame, but couldn't find any. I'm wondering if such a thing is possible and if yes, how should I proceed?

I'm writing an essay about how the rate of degradation of aspartame could be slowed down and wanted to attempt using some compounds to inhibit the reaction.

Comment: Hydrolysis under what conditions? In vivo? In aqueous solution?

Comment: aqueous solution

Answer (score 1):

Aspartame is hydrolysed in both acid and alkaline solution with the methyl ester being the first site hydrolysed, so control of the pH of the aqueous solution is important. Addition of buffer solutions would enable control of the pH, keeping it close to neutrality.

https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/buffers.html